# The Standard Model (SM) predicts mass ratios from book excerpt

Tags: mass, standard-model, higgs

I read a book excerpt in which the author states:

> "The SM predicts that the ratio of the muon mass/electron mass should be equal to the strange quark/down quark. This is known to be  mathematically false...   ~200::~20"

and now I cant find it again.

1. Can you please recite the source and/or explain (in laymen's) why the SM predicts this equality?

I understand that all particles should be massless w/o Higgs.

2. Is the SM saying something particular about these particles?
3. Is there a symmetry involved?
4. Is it a trivial statement?
5. Can we arbitrarily insert other pairs from the 3 generations into this equation?

Comment: I edited your title.  To me, "SM" means statistical mechanics.  This is a good example why acronyms and abbreviations should not be used without defining them, esp in titles.

Answer (score 2):

The Standard Model doesn't predict these numbers.  They're free parameters.  Treat that book with suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps thinking of the decay rates? The SM, more precisely, [CKM theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix), predicts the rate at which muons turn into muon neutrinos and electrons turn into electron neutrinos via a W decay is the same as the rate at which up quarks decay to down quarks with a W. But this was actually more of an observation than a prediction, however, it was important for predicting the third generation of quarks in concert with the observation of CP violation.

As was stated above, the masses of the standard model particles, and thus their ratios, are a property of the coupling constants in the standard model Lagrangian. With vanilla QFT, these are essentially considered fundamental  constants which are measured and not derivable by the theory.

However, some beyond the standard model theories do try to explain these ratios.

Comment: So the couplings are free parameters : meaning completely independent of all internal symmetries and mathematical relationship, even the normal hierarchy of successively heavier generations is not mandated. Given that they are implies a symmetry (yes?) but it is unconfirmed at this time having no theory about the couplings. Is that correct thinking?